# id always = 0 as result can't update record in db

Tags: java, spring-mvc

in java project use spring mvc, Hibernate :

Here model **Category**:

```
   import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

   @Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Long createdAt;
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Long updatedAt;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Long createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Long getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Long updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nCategory [id = " + id + ", name = " + name + ", createdAt = " + createdAt + ", updatedAt = "
                + updatedAt + "]";
    }

}
```

Here controller:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
@Controller
public class CategoryController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CategoryController.class);

    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "categoryService")
    public void setCategoryService(CategoryService categoryService) {
        this.categoryService = categoryService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/categories", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listCategories(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("category", new Category());
        model.addAttribute("listCategories", this.categoryService.getCategoryList());
        return "category";
    }

    // For add and update category both
    @RequestMapping(value = "/category/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addCategory(@ModelAttribute("category") Category category) {
        logger.info(">>>>>>>>> add/update category = " + category);
        if (category.getId() == 0) {
            // new category, add it
            category.setCreatedAt(System.currentTimeMillis());
            categoryService.addCategory(category);
        } else {
            // existing category, call update
            categoryService.updateCategory(category);
        }
        return "redirect:/categories";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String editCategory(@PathVariable("id") long id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("category", categoryService.getCategoyById(id));
        model.addAttribute("listCategories", this.categoryService.getCategoryList());
        return "category";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
    public String removeCategory(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        categoryService.removeCategory(id);
        return "redirect:/categories";
    }

}
```

Here my DAO impl:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.myproject.model.Category;

public class CategoryDAOImpl implements CategoryDAO {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CategoryDAOImpl.class);

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf) {
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    public void addCategory(Category category) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        logger.info(">>>>>>>>> insert category: " + category);
        session.persist(category);
        logger.info("Category saved successfully, Category Details = " + category);
    }

    public void updateCategory(Category category) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.update(category);
        logger.info("Category updated successfully, category Details=" + category);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Category> getCategoryList() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Category> categoryList = session.createCriteria(Category.class).list();
        for (Category category : categoryList) {
            logger.info("current category: " + category);
        }
        return categoryList;
    }

    public Category getCategoryById(long id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Category category = (Category) session.load(Category.class, new Long(id));
        logger.info("Category loaded successfully, Category details=" + category);
        return category;
    }

    public void removeCategory(long id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Category category = (Category) session.load(Category.class, new Long(id));
        if (null != category) {
            session.delete(category);
        }
        logger.info("Category deleted successfully, Category details = " + category);
    }

}
```

here jsp:

```
<body>
    <h1>Add a category</h1>

    <c:url var="addAction" value="/category/add"></c:url>

    <form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="category">
        <table>
            <c:if test="${!empty category.name}">
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="id">
                            <spring:message text="ID" />
                        </form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"
                            disabled="true" /> <form:hidden path="id" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:if>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="name">
                        <spring:message text="Name" />
                    </form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><c:if test="${!empty category.name}">
                        <input type="submit" value="<spring:message text="Edit Category"/>" />
                    </c:if> <c:if test="${empty category.name}">
                        <input type="submit" value="<spring:message text="Add Category"/>" />
                    </c:if></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
    <br>
    <h3>Category List</h3>
    <c:if test="${!empty listCategories}">
        <table class="tg">
            <tr>
                <th width="80">ID</th>
                <th width="120">Name</th>
                <th width="120">Created At</th>
                <th width="120">Updated At</th>
                <th width="60"></th>
                <th width="60"></th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${listCategories}" var="category">
                <jsp:setProperty name="createdAtDateValue" property="time"
                    value="${category.createdAt}" />
                <c:if test="${not empty category.updatedAt}">
                    <jsp:setProperty name="updatedAtDateValue" property="time"
                        value="${category.updatedAt}" />
                </c:if>
                <tr>
                    <td>${category.id}</td>
                    <td>${category.name}</td>
                    <td><fmt:formatDate value="${createdAtDateValue}"
                            pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" /></td>
                    <c:if test="${empty category.updatedAt}">
                        <td />
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${not empty category.updatedAt}">
                        <td><fmt:formatDate value="${updatedAtDateValue}"
                                pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" /></td>
                    </c:if>
                    <td><a href="<c:url value='/edit/${category.id}' />">Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a href="<c:url value='/remove/${category.id}' />">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

when when click Delete link it's success delete record. Nice. 
But when click Edit link change category's name  then:
**show select category with name and id**

Here screenshot:

[image]

As you can see **ID** success show.
Nice. But when I click **Edit category** it's add record. Not update. 
It's because here:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/category/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addCategory(@ModelAttribute("category") Category category) {
        logger.info(">>>>>>>>> add/update category = " + category);
        if (category.getId() == 0) {
            // new category, add it
            category.setCreatedAt(System.currentTimeMillis());
            categoryService.addCategory(category);
        } else {
            // existing category, call update
            categoryService.updateCategory(category);
        }
        return "redirect:/categories";
    }
```

always `category.getId()` return 0 .

Why?

Comment: Hi, could you add your Category.java class also?

Comment: Post the complete class. Also, do some debugging. Look at the generted HTML code of the page. Does it have a hidden inout field witht the right ID value? Open your browser dev tools, in the network panel, then submit the forem. What is submitted as the body of the request? Do you see the ID there? If you set a breakpoint or add a println in the setter for the ID (assuming there is one), is it called?

Comment: There you are. You have no setter for the ID. So Spring can't populate the ID from the request parameter.